# What is the meaning of エラ？

Tags: words

Watching a Youtube video this tshirt appeared:

[image: エラ]

What's エラ supposed to mean here? It has something to do with 偉? Sexual meaning? I googled a bit but didn't find any other examples.

Thanks!

Comment: Era, branchia, someone's name, etc... Where was this video taken?

Comment: It was taken in Osaka.

Comment: No, I mean, what kind of shop(or some sort) was this video taken?

Comment: No shop. Tshirt was in the background, it was a homeless tent in Nishinari-ku.

Answer (score 2):

This is a T-shirt designed and sold by the [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZ-Z_iLRVqx_7Llk4hp458g) of [恵良敏彦](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%81%B5%E8%89%AF%E6%95%8F%E5%BD%A6), a professional boxer and YouTuber. So エラ is simply his family name written in katakana. According to Wikipedia, he used to do support activities for the homeless in Osaka, which is probably why the T-shirt is there.

- [T-shirt online shop](https://tetujinera01.base.shop/)
- [路上生活者がＩ♥エラTシャツを！　西成あいりん地区](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwuuQBWCimI)